# Deploy just one role in Azure service project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, azure

Sorry I'm just starting out with Azure, hopefully the following question makes sense.

I have an Azure project with 3 roles. I'd need to deploy one of them right now, but the other 2 roles are far from being ready and I'd have no use in deploying them at the moment (and that would also make me pay for 3 instances, right?)

Would Visual Studio let me deploy just the role I'm interested in?

If not, is there a way to temporarely remove the other roles without losing their settings?

(Thank you for your answer Richard, I was hoping I could — for example — just comment out parts of the ServiceDefinition / ServiceConfiguration files to tell VS not to package the extra roles.)

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the projects you don't want to deploy from the 'roles' folder of your Cloud project, and they should be ignored.

You can easily add them back in when you're ready to use them.