# How to disable worker role in Azure project?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-worker-roles

I don't need worker role anymore, but I will in future, so I want to disable it but not remove it from project in Visual Studio. How can I tell VS to omit worker role deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469570/deploy-just-one-role-in-azure-service-project) helps. If you just delete the projects you don't want to deploy in the 'roles' folder, only roles defined in 'roles' are deployed. You should take care about configure 0 instances and check in Azure portal the role you have removed from "roles" folder it dissapears from Azure, remember in a cloud platform the bill si extremely related with the usage.

Comment: It's not allowed to set 0 instances, I tried. So delete it's config from Roles folder. I don't want to loose all settings there. Is deleting it's config really necessary?

Comment: Yes it is. you can get your settings back if you use source control.